# Using SMOTE on java raises Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, maven, weka, smote

I'm working on a project in java and I need to use Weka's API. I use Maven to manage dependencies and, in particular, I have the following one:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
   <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
   <version>3.8.5</version>
</dependency>
```

In this version, the SMOTE class is not kept, but I really need it; that's why I also added in my `pom.xml`  the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
   <artifactId>SMOTE</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

In my Java code, i also try to develop the `WalkForward` validation technique: I can prepare both *training set* and *testing set* for each step, so i can use them in a loop in which what I do is the following:

```java
for (...){
   var filtered = new FilteredClassifier();
   var smote = new SMOTE();
   filtered.setFilter(smote);
   filtered.setClassifier(new NaiveBayes());
   filtered.buildClassifier(trainingDataset);
   var currEvaluation = new Evaluation(testingDataset);
   currEvaluation.evaluateModel(filtered, testingDataset);
}
```

`trainingDataset` and `testingDataset` type is `Instances` and their value changes appropriately in each iteration. In the first iteration, no problem occurs, but in the second one the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!` is raised. The exception stack trace is:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeLo(TimSort.java:781)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:518)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.mergeCollapse(TimSort.java:448)
    at java.base/java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:245)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1441)
    at java.base/java.util.List.sort(List.java:506)
    at java.base/java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:179)
    at weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE.doSMOTE(SMOTE.java:637)
    at weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE.batchFinished(SMOTE.java:489)
    at weka.filters.Filter.useFilter(Filter.java:708)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.setUp(FilteredClassifier.java:719)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier.buildClassifier(FilteredClassifier.java:794)
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? 
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: I forgot to say I'm using `java 11.0.11`. 

**EDIT 2**: Based on the @fracpete answer, I deduce that the problem may be the sets creation. I state that I'm trying to predict bugginess of classes of another opensource project. Because of `Walk Forward`, I have 19 steps and should have 19 different training files and 19 testing files. To avoid this, I have a list of class `InfoKeeper` which keeps Instances for train and test for each step. During the creation of this array, i do the following:

1. from the base ARFF file, i crete 2 temporary files: training test file keeping version 1 data, testing set file keeping version 2 data. Then I read these temp ARFFs to create the Instances class. These will be kept by `InfoKeeper` related on step 1.
2. I append testing set file's row (only data, of course) in the training set files, so that it will keep version 1 and version 2 data. Then I override the training file to let it keeps the version 3 data. I read these temp ARFFs to get the Instances that will be kept by `InfoKeeper` related on step 2.

The code iterates on step 2 to create all the remaining `InfoKeeper`. May this operation be the problem?

I also tried to use @frecpete snippet, but the same error occurs. The files I used are the following:
[training set file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1irhHW580sgGwE6QRdS3dz8gIJhOrUaS_/view?usp=sharing) 
[testing set file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j8o3skOEZrElrxP4H9KieqWG8OAiPNOa/view?usp=sharing)


**EDIT 3**: this is how I compute files:

```java
public class FilesCreator {

    private File basicArff;
    private Instances totalData;

    private ArrayList<Instance> testingInstances;
    private File testingSet;
    private File trainingSet;

    /* *******************************************************************/

    public FilesCreator(File csvFile, File arffFile, File training, File testing) 
           throws IOException {
        var loader = new CSVLoader();
        loader.setSource(csvFile);
        this.totalData = loader.getDataSet(); // get instances object
        this.basicArff = arffFile;
        this.testingSet = testing;
        this.trainingSet = training;
    }

    private ArrayList<Attribute> getAttributesList(){
        var attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < this.totalData.numAttributes(); i++)
            attributes.add(this.totalData.attribute(i));
        return attributes;
    }

    private void writeHeader(PrintWriter pf) {
        // just write the attributes in the given file. 
        // f is either this.testingSet or this.trainingSet
        pf.append("@relation " + this.totalData.relationName() + "\n\n");
        pf.flush();
        var attributes = this.getAttributesList();
        for (Attribute line : attributes){
            pf.append(line.toString() + "\n");
            pf.flush();
        }
        pf.append("\n@data\n");
        pf.flush();
    }

    /* *******************************************************************/
    /* testing file */

    // testing instances
    private void computeTestingSet(int indexRelease){
        int i;
        int currIndex;
        // re-initialize the list
        this.testingInstances = new ArrayList<>();
        for (i = 0; i < this.totalData.numInstances(); i++){
            // first attribute is the release index
            currIndex = (int) this.totalData.instance(i).value(0);
            if (currIndex == indexRelease)
                testingInstances.add(this.totalData.instance(i));
            else if (currIndex > indexRelease)
                break;
        }
    }

    // testing file
    private void computeTestingFile(int indexRelease){
        this.computeTestingSet(indexRelease);
        try(var fp = new PrintWriter(this.testingSet)) {

            this.writeHeader(fp);
            for (Instance line : this.testingInstances){
                fp.append(line.toString() + "\n");
                fp.flush();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            var logger = Logger.getLogger(FilesCreator.class.getName());
            logger.log(Level.OFF, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }
    /* *******************************************************************/
    // training file
    private void computeTrainingFile(int indexRelease){
        int i;

        try(var fw = new FileWriter(this.trainingSet, true);
            var fp = new PrintWriter(fw)) {
            if (indexRelease == 1) {
                // first iteration: need the header.
                fp.print("");
                fp.flush();
                this.writeHeader(fp);
                for (i = 0; i < this.totalData.numInstances(); i++) {
                    if ( (int) this.totalData.instance(i).value(0) > indexRelease)
                        break;
                    fp.append(this.totalData.instance(i).toString() + "\n");
                    fp.flush();
                }
            }
            else {
                // in this case just append the testing instances, which
                // are the indexReleas+1-th data:
                for (Instance obj : this.testingInstances){
                    fp.append(obj.toString() + "\n");
                    fp.flush();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            var logger = Logger.getLogger(FilesCreator.class.getName());
            logger.log(Level.OFF, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }
    }

    /* *******************************************************************/
    // public method
    public void computeFiles(int indexRelease){
        this.computeTrainingFile(indexRelease);
        this.computeTestingFile(indexRelease + 1);
    }
}
```

The last public method is invoked inside a loop of another class, starting from 1 to 19:

```java
    FilesCreator filesCreator = new FilesCreator(csvFile, arffFile, training, testing);
    for (i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        filesCreator.computeFiles(i);
        /* do something with files, such as getting Instances and
           use them for SMOTE computation */
    }
```

**EDIT 4**: I removed duplicated instances from `totalData` in `FilesCreator` by doing the following:

```java
 var currDir = Paths.get(".").toAbsolutePath().normalize().toFile();
    var ext = ".arff";
    var tmpFile = File.createTempFile("without_replicated", ext, currDir);
    RemoveDuplicates.main(new String[]{"-i", this.basicArff.toPath().toString(), "-o", tmpFile.toPath().toString()});
    // output file has effective 0 instances repetitions 
    var arffLoader = new ArffLoader();
    arffLoader.setSource(tmpFile);
    this.totalData = arffLoader.getDataSet();
    Files.delete(tmpFile.toPath());
```

I cannot manually modify it because it's output of previous computation. The code works for iteration `2`, but get the same error for iteration `3`. 
The files for this iteration are:
[train_iteration4.arff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QaO252xcaHaiKyFyb4aixEK4H_csM01x/view?usp=sharing) 
[test_iteration4.arff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bw71PC9xOMBcnjpml80Ysdg0TDhNW__n/view?usp=sharing)
This is the very full arff file obtained by the previous snippet and it's the one which is loaded by `arffLoader.setSource(tmpFile);`: 
[full.arff](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k-0bJZBKZCMql_OMswHVGtp0z10HX4dl/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: What Java version are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using `java 11.0.11`. I'm going to add this information editing the question.

Comment: You'll have to post the code that generates your train/test sets as well.

Comment: Added in **EDIT 3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem changing the smote dependency in my `pom.xml` in:

```xml
<dependency>
   <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
   <artifactId>SMOTE</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.3</version>
</dependency>
```

In this version, I don't have any problem and my code runs as expected. Hope this will help others.

Answer (score 0):

I put together a quick example Maven project and I don't have any problems under Java 11 (`openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20`):

The example `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.github.fracpete</groupId>
  <artifactId>smote-test</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1</version>

  <name>smote-test</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
       <artifactId>weka-stable</artifactId>
       <version>3.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka</groupId>
       <artifactId>SMOTE</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>exec</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <executable>java</executable>
          <arguments>
            <argument>-classpath</argument>
            <classpath/>
            <argument>smote.SmoteTest</argument>
          </arguments>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

I've adapted your `FilesCreator` class to work with Java 8 syntax (easier to read for me) and to load an ARFF file instead of a CSV one. This class needs to go into `src/main/java/smote`:

```java
package smote;

import weka.core.Attribute;
import weka.core.Instance;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ArffLoader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class FilesCreator {

  private File basicArff;
  private Instances totalData;

  private ArrayList<Instance> testingInstances;
  private File testingSet;
  private File trainingSet;

  /* *******************************************************************/

  public FilesCreator(File fullArffFile, File arffFile, File training, File testing)
      throws IOException {
    ArffLoader loader = new ArffLoader();
    loader.setSource(fullArffFile);
    this.totalData = loader.getDataSet(); // get instances object
    this.basicArff = arffFile;
    this.testingSet = testing;
    this.trainingSet = training;
  }

  private ArrayList<Attribute> getAttributesList(){
    ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>();
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.totalData.numAttributes(); i++)
      attributes.add(this.totalData.attribute(i));
    return attributes;
  }

  private void writeHeader(PrintWriter pf) {
    // just write the attributes in the given file.
    // f is either this.testingSet or this.trainingSet
    pf.append("@relation " + this.totalData.relationName() + "\n\n");
    pf.flush();
    ArrayList<Attribute> attributes = this.getAttributesList();
    for (Attribute line : attributes){
      pf.append(line.toString() + "\n");
      pf.flush();
    }
    pf.append("\n@data\n");
    pf.flush();
  }

  /* *******************************************************************/
  /* testing file */

  // testing instances
  private void computeTestingSet(int indexRelease){
    int i;
    int currIndex;
    // re-initialize the list
    this.testingInstances = new ArrayList<>();
    for (i = 0; i < this.totalData.numInstances(); i++){
      // first attribute is the release index
      currIndex = (int) this.totalData.instance(i).value(0);
      if (currIndex == indexRelease)
    testingInstances.add(this.totalData.instance(i));
      else if (currIndex > indexRelease)
    break;
    }
  }

  // testing file
  private void computeTestingFile(int indexRelease){
    this.computeTestingSet(indexRelease);
    try(PrintWriter fp = new PrintWriter(this.testingSet)) {

      this.writeHeader(fp);
      for (Instance line : this.testingInstances){
    fp.append(line.toString() + "\n");
    fp.flush();
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FilesCreator.class.getName());
      logger.log(Level.OFF, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
  }
  /* *******************************************************************/
  // training file
  private void computeTrainingFile(int indexRelease){
    int i;

    try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(this.trainingSet, true);
    PrintWriter fp = new PrintWriter(fw)) {
      if (indexRelease == 1) {
    // first iteration: need the header.
    fp.print("");
    fp.flush();
    this.writeHeader(fp);
    for (i = 0; i < this.totalData.numInstances(); i++) {
      if ( (int) this.totalData.instance(i).value(0) > indexRelease)
        break;
      fp.append(this.totalData.instance(i).toString() + "\n");
      fp.flush();
    }
      }
      else {
    // in this case just append the testing instances, which
    // are the indexReleas+1-th data:
    for (Instance obj : this.testingInstances){
      fp.append(obj.toString() + "\n");
      fp.flush();
    }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(FilesCreator.class.getName());
      logger.log(Level.OFF, Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
    }
  }

  /* *******************************************************************/
  // public method
  public void computeFiles(int indexRelease){
    this.computeTrainingFile(indexRelease);
    this.computeTestingFile(indexRelease + 1);
  }
}
```

I then combined your two example ARFF files into a single one: `full.arff`

The `smote.SmoteTest` class located in `src/main/java/smote` (you'll need to change the hard-coded paths to the datasets):

```java
package smote;

import weka.classifiers.Evaluation;
import weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes;
import weka.classifiers.meta.FilteredClassifier;
import weka.core.Instances;
import weka.core.converters.ConverterUtils.DataSource;
import weka.filters.supervised.instance.SMOTE;

import java.io.File;

public class SmoteTest {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    FilesCreator filesCreator = new FilesCreator(new File("/home/fracpete/full.arff"), new File("."), new File("/home/fracpete/train.arff"), new File("/home/fracpete/test.arff"));
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
      System.out.println("--> " + i);
      filesCreator.computeFiles(i);
      System.out.println("Reading train");
      Instances trainingDataset = DataSource.read("/home/fracpete/train.arff");
      trainingDataset.setClassIndex(trainingDataset.numAttributes() - 1);
      System.out.println("Reading test");
      Instances testingDataset = DataSource.read("/home/fracpete/test.arff");
      testingDataset.setClassIndex(trainingDataset.numAttributes() - 1);
      System.out.println("smote");
      FilteredClassifier filtered = new FilteredClassifier();
      SMOTE smote = new SMOTE();
      filtered.setFilter(smote);
      filtered.setClassifier(new NaiveBayes());
      filtered.buildClassifier(trainingDataset);
      Evaluation currEvaluation = new Evaluation(testingDataset);
      currEvaluation.evaluateModel(filtered, testingDataset);
      System.out.println(currEvaluation.toSummaryString());
    }
  }
}
```

Then compile and run it:

```sh
mvn clean install
mvn exec:exec
```

This will fail as well at the second iteration.

However, after removing all the duplicate rows from the combined dataset, the error goes away.

My feeling is that SMOTE doesn't cope with duplicate rows in the input data.

NB: Before any run, make sure to remove the `train.arff` and `test.arff` files.

Comment: This is more or less  what i do: the only difference is about the Instances retrieval. Please read the **EDIT 2**.

Comment: Is removing rows a good thing to do on a dataset? Removing some instance of the row should change the impact of that row on the trained classifier: if there are more instance of a row, the trained classifier should be able to better identify classes whit that attributes. Am in wrong?

Comment: Having duplicates in your dataset can have unintended side-effects when performing cross-validation, with the same data being present in train and test set. That can lead to overly optimistic statistics. Introducing duplicates with a filter as part of a FilteredClassifier setup is safe to use.

Comment: I still have problems.. I really don't know what is happening